# When does a semisimple $\mathbb{C}$-algebra come from a group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups, oa.operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a semisimple $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. By the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, it is isomorphic to a direct product of matrix algebras:
$$ \mathcal{A} = \prod_{i=1}^m M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$$

**Under what conditions on $m,\,n_i$ can we say that $\mathcal{A} \simeq \mathbb{C}[G]$ for some finite group $G$?**.
This amounts to finding a group $G$ which has exactly $\#\{i \vert \, n_i = k \}$ non-isomorphic complex irreducible representations of dimension $k$, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that we must ask for $n_i \vert \sum_{i=1}^m n_i^2$, since the dimensions of irreps divide the order of a group.

Of course, one can also phrase this in terms of "which finite dimensional $C^*$ algebras arise as group $C^*$ algebras?", so one can also consider the question for arbitrary unital $C^*$ algebras, asking under what sufficient conditions does it come from a discrete group?

Any idea or reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314502/which-partitions-realise-group-algebras-of-finite-groups

Comment: This indeed seems to make a duplicate (I have the gr.group-theory golden badge which would close the question as duplicate from my only vote, so I don't vote). The other question has no accepted answer, probably because we don't really expect a definite answer.

Comment: @Ycor I see, I only saw that post from Mare's answer, so should I delete this question as a result (I agree it's a duplicate)?

Comment: Examples of easy necessary conditions: write $n=\sum n_i^2$. Then necessarily $|G|=n$. For many values of $n$ this gives restrictions. For instance, if $n$ is prime, square of prime, or some other values such as $15$, then this is plausible only if all $n_i=1$. If $n\ge 3$ is odd, or of the form $p^aq^b$, $G$ should be solvable, so $n_1$ should be $>1$.

Comment: Maybe. Actually the other question asks several questions, which leaves less focus on this very question, so I have no definite opinion.

Comment: If $n_1 \le n_2 \le \dots \le n_m$ and $n_2>1$, then $\sum_i n_i^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$ 
 (it is a property of the non-trivial perfect group). See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1357885/84284